# ag-grid implement master/detail functionality with rowModelType: 'enterprise' for server side for infinite scrolling.

Tags: ag-grid

I am not able to implement master/detail functionality with rowModelType: 'enterprise' in ag-grid version 17.1.1.

As per below link it is not possible to do.

https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/17.1.1/javascript-grid-master-detail/#row-models

Does anybody know a workaround to achieve the same?

Thanks for looking into this.